# How to select all text items on a slide using applescript?

Tags: applescript, keynote

I want to select only the text items on a slide using apple script.

```
tell application "Keynote"
    activate

    tell front document     

        tell slide 1
            select (every text item)
        end tell
        -- save
    end tell

end tell
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
error "Keynote got an error: every text item of slide 1 of document 1 doesn’t understand the “select” message." number -1708 from every text item of slide 1 of document 1
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You posted the same question on AD, https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309006/how-to-select-all-text-items-on-a-slide-using-applescript Please do not crosspost the same question on different SE sites.

Comment: I have an old version of Keynote, so what I'm seeing may be different than what you have, however, I'd suggest looking at the Keynote AppleScript Dictionary from the Library in Script Editor. There is no `select` _command_ in the version of Keynote that I have and probably why you're getting the error "... doesn’t understand the “select” message. ...".